# How to increase and decrease image size

Tags: javascript

I have an image having width set to `200px`, and height set to `200px`. For every click on image, it's width, and height should increase by `50px`, and when it's width and height reaches `500px`, it should decrease with `50px`, and when it will become `200px`, again it should increase with `50px` and so on. How can I do this?

The below code didn't work for me:

```
function Increase_Decrease() {
    var w = document.getElementById("img").width;
    var h = document.getElementById("img").height;
    if (w <= 500 && h <= 500){
        var w = document.getElementById("img").width += 50;
        var h = document.getElementById("img").height += 50;
    } else {
        var w = document.getElementById("img").width -= 50;
        var h = document.getElementById("img").height -= 50;
    }   
}
```

Comment: How is it "wrong"? Start there first: with a clear problem description. Also, this might lead to fun .. scaling issues, especially for non-square images. What about using CSS scaling ('zoom') instead?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the state of the zoom - whether the user is currently zooming **in** or **out**, and depending on the bounds you have specified, change the zoom state.

```js
const $image = document.querySelector('#image');
const delta = 50;
let zoom = +1;
$image.onclick = function() {
  const height = $image.getBoundingClientRect().height; // or $image.height
  if (height >= 500) {
    zoom = -1;
  } else if (height <= 200) {
    zoom = +1;
  }
  $image.height += zoom * delta;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://media1.tenor.com/images/9f8deeccdee39a5ed36a0a7ecfa3a1a8/tenor.gif?itemid=10044706" height="200" id="image" />
```

Also, keep in mind that you **don't** need to scale both width and height for an image. Scaling the width automatically scales the height, and vice versa, to maintain the *aspect ratio*.

Comment: This option is working, Thank you, but there is no other option? Coz i still don't know about querySelector or getBoundingClientRect.

Comment: Why don't you just use `$image.height`?

Comment: `querySelector` is just like jQuery's `$` but works in vanilla Javascript. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector. Instead of `$image.getBoundingClientRect().height`, you can use `$image.height` too (as @Cerbrus pointed out above, thanks!)

Comment: So, why are you using `getBoundingClientRect` if it's not necessary?

Comment: Just slipped my mind ;-) I did update my answer after you pointed it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're not keeping track of which way to go, you're just keeping it in the middle, you need to flip a switch once you hit either side to know which way to head.

Here I use `state` as the switch.

```js
const INCREASE = true
const DECREASE = false

let state = INCREASE

function Increase_Decrease() {
  const img = document.getElementById('img')
  if (state === INCREASE) {
    img.width += 50
    img.height += 50
    if (img.width >= 500) { state = DECREASE }
  } else {
    img.width -= 50
    img.height -= 50
    if (img.width <= 200) { state = INCREASE }
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="Increase_Decrease()">Click me</button>
<img id="img" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one.

```js
var onIncrease = true;
function IncDec() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myImg");
    if (onIncrease) {
     x.width += 50;
        x.height += 50;
    } else {
     x.width -= 50;
        x.height -= 50;
    }
    if (x.width == 500)
     onIncrease = false;
    if (x.width == 200)
     onIncrease = true;
    console.log("width: ", x.width, "height: ", x.height);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="myImg" onclick="IncDec()" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/0/01/200px-Langdon_Alger.png/revision/latest?cb=20120815160236" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="200" height="200">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one. I hope this will help you. No need to set height because height will adjust automatically based on width.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
var zoomIn = true, zoomOut = false;

function Increase_Decrease(){
var w = document.getElementById("img").width;
var h = document.getElementById("img").height;

if(w == 500) {
 zoomIn = false;
 zoomOut = true;
}
else if(w == 200) {
 zoomIn = true;
 zoomOut = false;
}

if(zoomIn && w <= 500) {
 var w1 = document.getElementById("img").width = w + 50; 
}
else if(zoomOut && w > 200) {
 var w1 = document.getElementById("img").width = w - 50; 
}

console.log(w,h);  
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<img id="img" onclick="Increase_Decrease()" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/animals" alt="img">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```